# Tables not looking properly on my email template

Tags: html, css, html-email

hope you're doing well. I'm working on an email template. and for some reason my code is not working properly (once tested through mail chimp). On my web browser looks amazing but of course, is taking full advantage of my html/css code.

I have a Table with 2 columns and within the right one I have another nested table with 3 rows. The thing is that, I'm trying to change the layout once the width of the screen is 599px or less, and is not working.

The final result is looking like this on the email provider (gmail):
[image]

This image of people on computers should represent the left column of the main table, the content below is the one of the nested table within the right column of the original table and both should take full advantage of the width of the wrapper (600px). for some reason is not working :( can someone help me sort this out?

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Email Template 1</title>
<style type="text/css">

html, body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

* {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}

div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

table, td {
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

table table table {
    table-layout: auto;
}

img {
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

.yshortcuts a {
    border-bottom: none !important;
}

a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
}
    
    .textLevel1 {
        font-size:30px;
    }
    
    .textLevel1b {
        font-size:22px;
    }
    
    .textLevel2 {
        font-size:18px;
    }
    
    .imageSideRight {
        width: 120px;
    }
    
    .ServiceSectionLeft {
        width: 250px;
    }
    
    .ServiceSectionRight {
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .notesAlignment {
        text-align: justify;
    }
    
    .whiteSpace {
        display: none;
    }
    
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .textLevel1 {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
    
    .textLevel1b {
        font-size:25px;
    }
    
    .textLevel2 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .imageSideRight {
        width: 60px;
    }
    
    .ServiceSectionLeft {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .ServiceSectionRight {
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .blueHidden {
        display: none;
        height: 0px;
    }
    
    .notesAlignment {
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    .whiteSpace {
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
    }
        
}
</style>
</head>
<body width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" style="font-family: sans-serif;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <br>
    
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td><center style="width: 100%;">

        <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;"> (Optional) This text will appear in the inbox preview, but not the email body. </div>
        
        <div style="max-width: 600px; width: 100%;"> 
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]--> 
          
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 0px; text-align: center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                  <div class="box" style="width: auto;">
                      <img style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto;" src="images/logoAnimation2.gif" alt="" border="0">
                  </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
            
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;" height="auto">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#243746" width="auto" style="background: url('./images/Image2.jpg') center / cover no-repeat #000000;"
>
                
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="imageSideRight">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px; background-color:#3A8DDE;" bgcolor="#468AC9">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:#ffffff; padding: 0px 20px;" height="60px" valign="top">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:#243746; padding: 0px 20px;" height="276px" valign="top">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>  
              </td>
            </tr>  
            </table>
            
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px; color:#ffffff; width: 100%;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#243746" width="100%">
                  <p style="font-size: 30px; mso-height-rule: exactly; padding: 10px 30px; text-align: left"><b><span class="textLevel1">Hello</span><span id="UserName" class="textLevel1"> Mitch!</span></b><br>
                      <span style="text-align:justify;" class="textLevel2">Your service request <span id="UserRequestId"><b>#452847</b></span> with the followings details has been creataed and assigned to <span id="SupportTeamAssigned"><u>John P</u></span>.</span>
                  </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
            
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" height="60px" style="max-width: 600px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 0px; text-align: center" bgcolor="#ffffff"></td>
            </tr>
          </table> 
            
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;" height="auto">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#243746" style="height:280px; background: url('./images/Image1.jpg') center / cover no-repeat #000000;" class="ServiceSectionLeft">
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="height: auto;" class="ServiceSectionRight">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px; background-color:#3A8DDE; height: auto;" bgcolor="#468AC9">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                            <div class="whiteSpace"></div>
                            <img src="images/iconSupport.png" width="80px" height="80px" alt="Support Icon" border="0" style="height: 80px; width:80px; padding: 0px 30px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:#ffffff; padding: 0px 30px;" height="140px" valign="top">
                            <p style="mso-height-rule: exactly;">
                            <span id="ServiceTitle" class="textLevel1b"><b>Service Title</b></span><br>
                            <span id="ServiceDescription" class="textLevel2">Service Description</span><br>
                            <span id="ServiceCategory" class="textLevel2">Category</span><br>
                            <span id="ServiceDate" class="textLevel2">5/1/21</span></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:#3A8DDE; padding: 0px 20px;" height="60px" valign="top" class="blueHidden">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>  
              </td>
            </tr>  
            </table>
            
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" height="auto" style="max-width: 600px; color: #ffffff;">
            <tr bgcolor="#3A8DDE" style="background-color:#3A8DDE;">
                <td rowspan="3" width="30px"></td>
                <td style="text-align:justify;" height="auto">
                    <p style="mso-height-rule: exactly; padding:20px 0px;"><span class="textLevel2">If you’re shipping devices in for repair or replacement, please include Service Request # and ship it to:</span></p>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="3" width="30px"></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#3A8DDE" style="background-color:#3A8DDE;">
                <td style="text-align:justify; border: 2px solid #ffffff; padding: 0px 20px;">
                    <p style="mso-height-rule: exactly;"><span class="textLevel1b"><b>Mtech</b></span><br>
                    <span id="ServiceRequestID" class="textLevel2">Service Request #</span><br>
                    <span id="PrimaryCentre" class="textLevel2">Primary Service Center</span><br>
                    <span id="CentreAddress" class="textLevel2">Service Centre Address</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#3A8DDE" style="background-color:#3A8DDE; height: 50px;" height="50px">
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="30" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px; color: #243746;">
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="notesAlignment">
                  <p style="mso-height-rule: exactly;"><span class="textLevel2"><b>Note:</b> Assets Recovery (Device Buy-Back and Recycling) transactions are considered accepted and ownership transfered upon receipt of devices and purchase orders delviered.</span></p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
           
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
            <tr>
              <td height="340px" width="100%" style="background-color: #243746; background: url('./images/Image2.jpg') center / cover no-repeat #000000;">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
            
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" height="auto" style="max-width: 600px; color: #ffffff;">
            <tr bgcolor="#E54C37" style="background-color:#E54C37;">
                <td rowspan="3" width="30px"></td>
                <td style="text-align:justify;" height="auto">
                    <br>
                    <p style="mso-height-rule: exactly; text-align: left;"><span class="textLevel1"><b>Require to request a Buy Back?</b></span><br>
                        <span class="textLevel2">Assets Recovery transactions should be redirected to Mobility - Assets Recovery.</span>
                    </p>
                    <br>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="3" width="30px"></td>   
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E54C37" style="background-color:#E54C37;">
                <td style="text-align:justify; border: 2px solid #ffffff; padding: 0px 20px;">
                    <p style="font-size:18px; mso-height-rule: exactly;"><span class="textLevel1b"><b>Mobility</b></span><br>
                    <span class="textLevel2">Address</span><br>
                    <span class="textLevel2">Address.</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E54C37" style="background-color:#E54C37; height: 50px;" height="50px">
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 40px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:12px; text-align: center; color: #999999;">
                <webversion style="color:#999999; text-decoration:underline; font-weight: bold;">View as a Web Page</webversion>
                <br>
                <br>
                  <a href="">
                      <img src="./images/mobilityfooter.png" width="220px" height="auto" alt="footerLogo"/>
                    
                  </a>
                <br><br><br>
                <span class="mobile-link--footer">Mobility<br>345 Park Avenue</span> <br>
                <br>
                <unsubscribe style="color:#888888; text-decoration:underline;">unsubscribe</unsubscribe></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
            
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]--> 
          </div> 
        </center></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mailchimp offers no support for custom templates (Feb 2021). I can tell your template has not been run through their system because tags like `<html>` do not have an in-lined style sheet. Maichimp is complete garbage. Spare yourself a lot of headache and use any other email service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Can we get more detail around what email client you're seeing this in and what device?
I can see issues in Outlook iOS but they differ to what you've shown.

I'm seeing a fair number of issues with the code:

1. width and height attributes (so not the CSS properties) have the units included i.e. `width="80px" height="80px"`. When declaring the attribute versions of dimensions, no need to include the unit format. So it should simply be `width="80" height="80" OR style="width:80px; height:80px;"`
2. Max-width is used pretty heavily, however there are no fall backs for Outlook which consists of ghost tables - https://gist.github.com/elidickinson/5525752
3. Styling on table rows can be pretty sketchy. I would recommend shifting those styles to a table cell or even a table at a stretch.
4. Use of cellspacing & cellpadding is also a bit sketchy as it can have differing results. Would recommend setting CSS padding on a table cell or margin on a div.
5. `height="auto" & height:auto;` are used a lot on tables and table cells. These two elements will naturally auto the height anyway. Not a biggie but not needed if trying to keep clean code.
6. Background images have no Outlook support - https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-background-images-in-email/

Also one thing to note, Outlook has major rendering issues:
[image]